# Dynamic forms on angular

Tags: angular, dynamicform, database-driven

we're planning on upgrading our current website (asp.net worbforms) to a single page application using angular. I'm not yet that fully familiar with angular, but is dynamic forms doable on angular? (Database driven pages)

On our current website users can create custom questionnaire forms by creating new questions 
Example:
Question 1: (radio button) Y/N "Do you have a driver's license?
Question 2: (Date picker) Birthday
Question 3: (Textbox) Tell me something about your self
Question 4: (Dropdown) Country
etc..

These created questions are then saved to the database and is then loaded on a page for users to answer and their answers are saved on the database. So each forms are different depending on the the one who created it.

Is this doable on angular?

Comment: you can use this npm [package](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly) for dynamic forms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example of how to build a dynamic form with validation in Angular 8 using Reactive Forms. The example is a simple order form for selecting the number of tickets to purchase and entering a name and email address for each ticket. All fields are required and email fields must contain a valid email address.

Please follow the [link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example) for reference